# Is MEF Production ready?

Tags: mef

I have to create a pluggable web app at work and I was looking at MEF which is supposed to give all the infrastructure needed for plugin model application, however I see it's still in preview, but I was wondering if anyone has used it on a production application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MEF V1 shipped](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gblock/archive/2010/06/03/mef-has-shipped.aspx).

Comment: oops, I was checking the codeplex page, maybe I looked at the next version preview, well thanks.

Comment: no, for some reason they never updated the codeplex site after it shipped